# Typescript Type resolution of tuple members - why does this compile?

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

### Playground

[You can find a playground with the code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG0BEBJAIgGQFEMBdKAH3QxgBUBBAJWqwDkBxAfWYIHV2BhAPLMAagXoxaTISXKU+ACVrMuedrT5NRGADRQqATWZ8CODLIwEAGgAU8A+i1YkA3ACgAxgHsAdgGdgUP6IEACMUKiYuIQy8L6wCEjOUAD0yVACANIePv6BCRAATOFyisoEquqaRLoWNnYObDFxcMFJqelZ7V5+AUFIAMzFkfjVela29o5N8a0paTieEHHengFeALZgAJYANhCurgBmAK7e7sBbPlDriO4AFksAPNRQEAAeSN4AJnFo-gBOW28AHNSBQ-sBASDdACgaDdJZitQ0AAGYi6fRItAhYgAPgAFK4oFAAG7wHbHCAALig1G0RKg9wg7gA1jTkWj6cSmayCgB+GkED7-eDnZ66NCWDF47HEVwASigAG8Gf8IMBjv9vKTyZTUaRkIbGQ9WVAAGRmqD4nksop8nUUiCy8JGm1FGmQynytwAXwO3Vyhy2-1yqBuwCZvnxfVCNSiRG9cygnv2Ad6zJ8X2K4cj0fyBRqCiUKjUGiwWkTqRT2R6ybuwazYduDyjMYLeiLZQqZa0NRghmMpkryUO5N8+1c7WoDygh08Ox2ngA7nCoFs4qOduO19rgDP-qcLusILoAEbHAJYKBLzzHHZZpfwbwBLYBYCeWfwXZQclq+BfEAfzWTxNl2CAAFojwgAA6GtA1vf492zZsljzYJ22wEYdD0fsjBMDBE39HJ5xgxdgXxJUgxDYAYQzb5dD3BtdDnTU9x9b0gA)

Given the following type definition:

```js
type State = ["IDLE"] | ["STARTING_NEW_CONVERSATION"] | ["CHANNEL_ACTIVE", "SYNCED" | "EXPLORING"];
const state: State = ...
```

and the following helper method:

```js
export function matches<T extends [string] | [string, string], X = T[0], Y = T[1]>(
  value: T,
  check: T[0],
  check2?: Extract<T, [X, Y]>[1]
) {
  return value[0] === check && (check2 ? value[1] === check2 : true);
}

// another variation...

export function matches<T extends [string] | [string, string]>(
  value: T,
  check: T[0],
  check2?: T extends [infer X, infer Y] ? Extract<T, [X, Y]>[1] : never
) {
  return value[0] === check && (check2 ? value[1] === check2 : true);
}
```

It *mostly* works - However, I can call it like that

```js
matches(state, "IDLE", "EXPLORING")
```

And this is OK for the compiler - I would have expected the type for the second argument to be resolved to `never` or `undefined`.

- The value `["IDLE", "EXPLORING"]` is not assignable to `state`
- Writing `Extract<State, ["IDLE", "EXPLORING"]>` correctly extracts `never`

So, my question is

#### Why is the call to "matches" with the value representing an invalid type succeeding?

Comment: Could you setup minimal reproducible example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play? Currently it is not really clear as function signature expects tuple as first parameter, but you pass a string

Comment: `matches("IDLE", "EXPLORING")` has no reference at all to the `State` type. Is that a typo in your question? In the playground this call generates the error `"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string] | [string, string]'`

Comment: True @ccarton  - the state value is the first parameter

Comment: Hello @AlekseyL. - I've added a playground - running it fails for some reason beyond my control, but it shows that everything compiles fine, even though from my POV it shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't narrow the type for `T` based on the value you pass in the second parameter.

Given this code:

```
type State = ["IDLE"] | ["STARTING_NEW_CONVERSATION"] | ["CHANNEL_ACTIVE", "SYNCED" | "EXPLORING"];
const state: State = {} as any

export function matches<T extends [string] | [string, string], X = T[0], Y = T[1]>(
  value: T,
  check: T[0],
  check2?: Extract<T, [X, Y]>[1]
) {
  return value[0] === check && (check2 ? value[1] === check2 : true);
}

matches(state, "IDLE", "EXPLORING")
```

Typescript infers the following types for the arguments:

```
value: State
check: "IDLE" | "STARTING_NEW_CONVERSATION" | "CHANNEL_ACTIVE"
check2: "SYNCED" | "EXPLORING"
```

When you pass `"IDLE"` as the second parameter TS just looks at it and says "Yup, that matches `"IDLE" | "STARTING_NEW_CONVERSATION" | "CHANNEL_ACTIVE"` and continues. It doesn't narrow anything.

If you need to enforce constraints on the types of the second and third arguments based on each other, then you should put a common type that you are constraining in the template argument list and refer to it from both arguments:

```
function matches<T extends State, X extends T[0], Y extends T[1]>(
  value: T,
  check: X,
  check2?: Extract<T, [X, Y]>[1],
) {
  return value[0] === check && (check2 ? value[1] === check2 : true);
}

type State = ["IDLE"] | ["STARTING_NEW_CONVERSATION"] | ["CHANNEL_ACTIVE", "SYNCED" | "EXPLORING"];
const state: State = {} as any

matches(state, 'IDLE', ) // WORKS
matches(state, 'CHANNEL_ACTIVE', 'EXPLORING') // Works
matches(state, 'IDLE', 'EXPLORING') // ERROR: Argument of type '"EXPLORING"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.
```

The key difference is that we define the type `X` in the template list and then use it in *both* of the argument constraints. This forces TS to infer a single type `X` that satisfies both arguments. Without that, the constraints for your arguments are not related.

(Edit: Updated to a simplified solution that is a lot closer to your original code)

Comment: Very cool and plausible - wasn't too far off, basically "check" wasn't constrained enough.